# Question about SURF descriptor euclid distance

Tags: c++, opencv, euclidean-distance, surf, descriptor

I use c++ opencv(3.4.1) SURF(xfeatures2d) to get keypoints and descriptor.

```
Ptr<SURF> detector1 = SURF::create(800.0);
detector1->detect(img1, keypoints_1);
detector1->detect(img2, keypoints_2); 
detector1->compute(img1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1);
detector1->compute(img2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2);
```

And then I want to get EuclidDistance like this for just studying algorithm.

```
double EuclidDistance(Mat descriptors_1, Mat descriptors_2, int length=64)
{
    double distance_L2 = norm(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, NORM_L2);
    return distance_L2;
}
```

But, two descriptors size is not same.like descriptors_1 size is 64 x 436, descriptors_2 size is 64 x 328. How to get Euclid distance correctly? 
Just throw away left area of matrix? Am I misunderstand now about matching process in surf? give me some advice.

Comment: Seems like you have 436 points from image 1, and 328 from image 2. Each descriptor has length of 64. If you want to find matches, try comparing each descriptor from the first image to all descriptors from the second image. (If the distance is below some threshold, it's a match)

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate it.